# Change OpenCV float image default palette range from [0 1] to some custom [min max]

Tags: c++, opencv

Is it possible to change OpenCV float image default palette range from [0 1] to a custom [min max]?

```
Mat img(h, w, CV_32FC1); // Create float image
DoStuff(img); // Fill data
ChangePaletteMinMax(img); // Is it possible to change the default palette? Or I need to normalize it to [0 1] ?
imshow("My float image", img); // The greyscale is only from 0 to 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `normalize()` to set your custom range:

```
normalize(img, dst, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1)
```

In the above, the range has been set to 0 - 255.

[More details here](https://cppsecrets.com/users/168511510411111711412197115105110104975764103109971051084699111109/C00-OpenCV-cvnormalize.php)